# How to perform a join and/or cogroup operation on two maps in scala

Tags: scala, join

I am looking to match keys in two maps and produce a Tuple2 of their cogroup.

so:

```
val m = Map("a" -> "ma", "b" -> "mb")
val n = Map("b" -> "nb", "a" -> "na" )

val join = m.join(n)
{ b -> ['mb', 'nb'], a -> ['ma', 'na']}
```

Note the ordering of the keys is not important, but it IS expected that the order of the values be retained according to the join order.

It is of course possible to do a 'nested loops' operation- i.e. take every key of m and do lookups against n to create the result.

```
m.map{ case (k,v) =>
          (k, (v,n(k)))
     }
res4: collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, String)] = Map(a -> (ma,na), b -> (mb,nb))
```

So we could put this into a function:

```
  def join[T <: Comparable[T]](a: Map[T,_], b: Map[T,_]) = {
      a.map{ case (k,v) =>
        (k, (v, b(k)))
      }
  }
```

Try it out:

```
scala> join(m,n)
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Any, Any)] = Map(a -> (ma,na), b -> (mb,nb))
```

Just wondering if there were any other approaches to this.

**UPDATE**  Yes this was a duplicate of "merge map".

In any case the best answer is close to the accepted one below:

```
 (a.toSeq++b.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toList)
```

Comment: Re: duplicate:  OK I had searched for join and cogroup, not merge.   But now there is an answer to this question:  what is the procedure to follow at this point?

Comment: "duplicate" doesn't mean you cant accept or upvote answers to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
(m.toSeq ++ n.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

In this case m & n do not have to have same key sets

Comment: That's good. One thing  is that the values outputs end up as an ArrayBuffer - as opposed to a Tuple2. Not sure yet whether that matters to me.